# Can't run uWebSockets on CentOS 7 with glibc-2.17

Tags: c++, node.js, glibc, uwebsockets

```
Error: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /root/workspace/backend/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws_linux_x64_72.node)
```

Latest `glibc` version for CentOS 7 is 2.17.
I know that latest version for CentOS 8 is 2.30 but I *can't upgrade*, because my VDS depends on host's machine kernel (which is very old).

Is there any way to run/compile it with `glibc-2.17` or update `glibc`?

EDIT:
My kernel version is `2.6.32-042stab141.3`.

I can build it and install to `/opt/glibc-2.18` without errors, but when I trying to use this I see `Segmentation fault` error.

> P.S. I builded it successfully on Fedora 23 with same OpenVZ kernel.

Comment: Did you try to clone its repo and build it?
In its docs says it is header only and depends on uSockets C library, so you would need to build it with your glibc and install it, then use uWebSockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built a custom binary (and tutorial) that will solve your exact problem.

Read it here: https://github.com/dominicklee/uWebSockets.js-for-Centos7

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to run/compile it with glibc-2.17

Yes: just do it (download source, build on your target machine, profit).

> or update glibc?

You didn't say what your "very old kernel" is, but if GLIBC-2.18 supports it, then yes, you can update GLIBC.

However, any mistake you make in the process may make your system un-bootable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59149640/50617).

Comment: I have a full backup of my system, so I can do anything.